# How to build an e-commerce site in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to develop ecommerce site like homeshop18 Where one store but different merchent can upload their own product on admin section and also view their own product and categories but in front end shows all merchants products (i.e I want to restrict user as per product and category).Please advice which plugin.

Comment: Frankly for a e-commerce site I would create a custom website using php-laravel instead of using wordpress, as after a point wordpress customization of plugins give up and may require you to entirely write/switch the website at a much later point, when it needs upgarde or requires some customisation not possible using plugins. And that will be  one hell of a job.

Comment: Disagree with Mustada Sabir. We have built very complicated ecommerce websites using wordpress and woocommerce. You can create everything you'd imagined either with some plugin or by writing some lines of code. It is much easier than creating everything form zero using a framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do so, install wordpress and add the woocommerce plugin for the eshop. To have multiple vendors selling their products at your store simply add the woocommerce vendors plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-vendors/